# Calculate $\int \frac{ 1}{\cos a\>+\> \cos x} \, dx $ where $a$ is a constant

Tags: integration

How to evaluate
$$\int \frac{ 1}{\cos(a) + \cos(x)} \, dx $$
where $a$ is a constant?

**My Attempt:**

I substituted in the integral:
$A = \cos(a)$
On solving by usual method, I got:
$$ \frac{2 \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{A-1} . \tan(\frac{x}{2})}{\sqrt{A+1}})}{\sqrt{A^2-1}} + C$$
where $C$ is the constant of integration and $A^2> 1$.
Now that means this solution does not work for $A = \cos(a)$.
How should I proceed with this question in the simplest possible way (beginner's approach) so that it works for $A^2 < 1$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A^2<1$, the denominator has zeros. how do you rectify that arctan in your answer? Example: if your $cos(a)=0.5$, your integral takes of the form $\frac{-4}{t^2-3}$ through the tangent half angle formula. That integral won't turn into an arctan, it will be logarithms.

Comment: @imranfat If I am not wrong,  $A^2 < 1$ makes the denominator imaginary! If you can suggest me how I can modify my initial steps, that will be great!

Comment: It does make the denominator imaginary, but realize that the integral has a factorable denominator, so through partial fraction decomposition, the anti derivative consists of $ln$ terms and not an arctan.

Comment: @imranfat Thank you for suggesting me that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
\int \frac{ 1}{\cos a+ \cos x} \, dx
&=\int \frac{ 1}{2\cos \frac{x-a}2 \cos \frac{x+a}2} \, dx\\
&= \frac1{2\sin a}\int\left(\frac{\sin \frac{x+a}2}{ \cos \frac{x+a}2} -\frac{\sin \frac{x-a}2}{ \cos \frac{x-a}2} \right)dx\\
&= \frac1{\sin a} \ln\bigg|\frac{ \cos \frac{x-a}2}{\cos \frac{x+a}2 }\bigg|+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution
$$
t=\tan(x/2)
$$
Then
$$
\cos a+\cos x=\cos a+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac{1+\cos a-(1-\cos a)t^2}{1+t^2}
$$
and
$$
dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt
$$
Now, for $\cos a\ne1$, set $b=\sqrt{(1+\cos a)/(1-\cos a)}$ and the integral becomes
$$
\frac{1}{b^2}\int\frac{2}{b^2-t^2}\,dt
$$
that's easily dealt with by using partial fractions:
$$
\frac{2}{b^2-t^2}=\frac{1/b}{b-t}+\frac{1/b}{b+t}
$$
The particular case when $\cos a=1$ can be treated separately.